# Check if the record updated is the last record of the table in a trigger

Tags: sql, plsql

In a trigger I need to know if the row that is being updated is the "last" row.
I need to know this because only if it is the "last" row, I need to update another table.

I know that I could use a **COMPOUND TRIGGER** with an **AFTER STATEMENT** to identify if the record updating is the "Last", but I wonder if there is an easier way?

EX:
table **person** :

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |   name    |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |   Bob     |
| 2    |   Kenny   |
+------+-----------+
```

table **relation_person_event**:

```
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
|  id  | id_Person |   id_event |   date     |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1    |   1       |     2000   | 2018-01-01 |
| 2    |   1       |     2195   | 2017-11-11 |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

The trigger is on the table **relation_person_event**.
I need to update an old table that cannot have more than 1 relation between person and event.
The last record is determined by the column date.

*EDIT*
**The old table** :

```
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
|  id  | id_Person |   id_event |   date     |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1    |   1       |     2000   |            |
| 2    |   2       |     3589   |            |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

All those tables are just to give a simple example of how the database is constructed. I want to push all the information from the new table to the old one.

Is there a way figuring if the record updating is the "last" record in a trigger without a **COMPOUND TRIGGER** with an **AFTER STATEMENT**?

Comment: Why do you need a Trigger? handle that update in the application logic. Also, when you say  "I need to update an old table", what's the definition of that table and which column you want to update?

Comment: @KaushikNayak The old table is bound to be destroyed in a couple of years max. It is not mapped in the application. Since it will be destroyed, it will be easier to destroy a trigger rather than modifying the application.

Comment: Well, changing the application in that case would be to write a separate procedure for it, ( or even better run it every day/week or whatever suits you as a scheduled job if it's possible), simply comment it once the old table is removed. A trigger would mean unnecessary load on the main table as long as it's being updated.

Comment: I understand what you say but changing the application means a major production graduation (in my place of work). The destruction of a trigger is strangly not seen as a graduation. I also thought about a scheduled job, but it is not appropriate for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is NO.
I have to do a **COMPOUND TRIGGER** to be able to do a select in the table that is mutating.

my trigger looks something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER relation_person_event_AUR_TR
   FOR UPDATE
   ON relation_person_event
COMPOUND TRIGGER

  date_to_update relation_person_event.date%TYPE;
  idPerson       relation_person_event.id_Person%TYPE;
  idevent        relation_person_event.id_event%TYPE;
  NB_BIGGER      NUMBER;

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    -- I can't access the :NEW in the AFTER STATEMENT, 
    -- so I need to save up the variables that I might use in the update.
    date_to_update := :NEW.DATE;
    idPerson := :NEW.id_Person;
    idevent := :NEW.id_event;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NB_BIGGER
      FROM relation_person_event T
     WHERE T.DATE > date_to_update;

    -- If 0, means that im updating the "last" row.
    IF NB_BIGGER = 0 THEN 
      UPDATE old_table O
         SET O.date = date_to_update,
             O.id_event = idevent
       WHERE O.id_Person = idPerson;
    END IF;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END relation_person_event_AUR_TR;
```

This is the only way that I found to verify something in the tables that I am updating.